# My form2 does not show / works correctly

Tags: c#, winforms

I want to make a program that reminds me of things. I pass a text, the time in minutes and then I press the Remember button. But when Form2 opens with the message, none of the elements are displayed. Form2 shows only the background, without the "Blz" button or the labels.

Below I leave the code snippets that I consider relevant. The rest are just buttons with simple routines, such as power example this.Hide () or this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Minimized.

Form1 Code

```
using System;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Timers;

namespace Alerta
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        FormMens Mensagem = new FormMens(); //it's form2
        System.Timers.Timer tempo;

    ...

    private void buttonLembrar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Hide();
        tempo = new System.Timers.Timer() { Enabled = true };
        tempo.Interval = (Decimal.ToInt32(numericMinutos.Value) * 60) * 1000 + 0.001;
        tempo.Elapsed += Lembrete;
        tempo.Start();
    }

    private void Lembrete(Object source, ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        tempo.Stop();

        Mensagem.texto = tboxLemb.Text;
        Mensagem.Activate();
        Mensagem.TopMost = true;
        Mensagem.Show();
    }
```

Form2 (FormMens)

```
using System;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Alerta
{
    public partial class FormMens : Form
    {
        public string texto;

    ...

    private void btFec_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Hide();
        Application.OpenForms["Form1"].Show();
    }

    ...

    private void FormMens_Activated(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.tboxTexto.Text = this.texto;
        //Console.Beep(400, 800);
    }
```

IMAGES HERE:

[image: Form1]

[image: Form2]

Information:
SO - Windows 10 15063.540
Visual Studio 17 - Version 15.2
Net Framework 4.5.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

System.Timers.Timer is not a timer that runs on the GUI thread.  Either use a WinForms timer, or invoke the second form on the GUI thread:

```
this.BeginInvoke(new Action(() => {
  Mensagem.texto = tboxLemb.Text;
  Mensagem.Show();
}));
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have:

```
public FormMens 
{
    InitializeComponent();
}
```